# Flex - text cursor overwrites adjacent control in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe, ria

I have a flex datagrid (an advancedDatagrid precisely) due different columns.

The fourth and fifth columns have an editor which display a maskedtextinput for enabling the field editing.
The adjacent column (6th) is clickable (rendered though a linkbutton).

the issue is that if the fifth column shows the textinput after user interaction (after clicking/selecting text/typing) moving the mouse over the linkbutton doesn0't shows the hand cursor, and clicking is not working.

Enlarging the column size makes this issue disappear and the hand cursor is correctly displayed, so I guess it's something related to default width of the textinput used in the fifth column.

Those 2 imageds shows the issue before and after enlarging the column:

[image: Can't click on sixth column]

[image: Click permitted after enlarging column]

This is the editor code for the textinput column, I tried to reduce the width manually costraining it to the real size of the column.

```
    <s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%" 
     xmlns:components="it.sabacom.generale.view.components.*"
     focusIn="mxadvanceddatagriditemrenderer1_focusInHandler(event)"
     focusEnabled="true">
    <mx:VBox width="50" horizontalAlign="center">
    <controls:MaskedTextInput id="smOraFine" inputMask="##:##" change="error10=true;" 
                              width="50" text="{data.hhFine} "/>
</mx:VBox>
```

I even tried to set `mouseChildren="false" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true"` on the clickable column, with no result.